# Find number of differences in 2 strings

Tags: c#, .net, php, c++, python

```
int n = string.numDifferences("noob", "newb"); // 2
```

??

Comment: Take a look at one of the methods for [measuring edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance).

Comment: For purposes of this question, what constitutes a "difference"? Unless you answer that question, the best answers you can get will be those that point you at the range of possible algorithms associated with different definitions of the question, as any concrete suggestion would be accurate only for a single definition of the problem.

That is to say: Your question is too vague.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The number you are trying to find is called the **[edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)**.  Wikipedia lists several algorithms you might want to use; the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) is a very common way of finding the edit difference between two strings of the same length (it's often used in error-correcting codes); the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is similar, but also takes insertions and deletions into account.  Wikipedia, of course, lists several others (*e.g.* [Damerau-Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau-Levenshtein_distance), which includes transpositions); I don't know which you want, as I'm no expert and the choice is domain-specific.  One of these, though, should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only want to compare characters at the same indices, the following C# solution (using methods provided by LINQ) should do the trick:

```
var count = s1.Zip(s2, (c1, c2) => c1 == c2 ? 0 : 1).Sum();
```

This "zips" the two strings, and then returns 0 for each index where the characters are the same and 1 for each index where they differ. Then we simply sum the numbers and we get the result.

Comment: See my comment for @Anthony's solution above. It's the same problem here: you assume naive transformation from `s1` to `s2`, and that doesn't yield the shortest edit distance.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Yes, and I mention that in the first sentence :-). It's not clear whether the question is how to calculate simple naive count like this or something more complicated...

Answer (score 1):

You already got excellent answers if you mean "edit distance".  If you just mean "number of characters that differ" (for two strings of the same length), in Python, the simplest approach would be:

```
sum(c1!=c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))
```

and if you also want to add the length difference, append

```
+ abs(len(s1) - len(s2))
```

Of course, if you *do* want edit distances, this approach would be far too simplistic;-).

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
class AnagramStringDifference
{   public int AnagramStringDifferenceString A, String B)
    {   int diff=0,Ai=0,Bi=0;
        char[] Aa= A.toCharArray();
        char[] Bb= B.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(Aa);
        Arrays.sort(Bb);
        while(Ai<Aa.length && Bi< Bb.length)
        {   int c=Character.compare(Aa[Ai],Bb[Bi]);        
            if(c<0)
            {   diff++;
                Ai++;
            }else if(c>0)
            {   diff++;
                Bi++;
            }else if(c==0)
            {    Ai++;
                 Bi++;
            }
        }
        diff+=Math.abs((Aa.length-Ai)-(Bb.length-Bi));
        return diff;
    }
}
```

P.S. I got asked such a similar difficult question from Codility online test for online job application, with around only 2 hours limit to 4 hard questions. I wonder how overcrowded the IT industry is, or how much unreasonable pressure that management places on IT workers, if temp agency recruiters can get away asking such an difficult question for screening an entry-level pay technical support job.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def differences(s1, s2):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        count += int(s1[i] != s2[1])
#    count += math.sqrt( (len(s1) - len(s2)) **2) #add this line if the two strings are of different length and differences counts the how many characters one string has more than the other.
    return count
```

Hope this helps